# Nuxt nested route not navigating properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a simple navigation in my `nuxt` app. My folder structure in the pages folder looks like

```
 - pages
   - auth
     - signup.vue
       - index.vue
```

In my `index.vue` I have the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-child/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have a global navbar component in the components folder used by the default component in the layouts folder. So in my navbar I have `nuxt-link` that looks like:

```
<nuxt-link
    to="auth/signUp"
  >
    <v-btn class="hidden-sm-and-down white--text" text>Signup</v-btn>
  </nuxt-link>
```

This works fine when I click signup the first time and takes me to the signup page but if I click signup when I am in the signup page it takes me to `auth/auth/signup`. I tried moving the index.vue page out of the auth folder and placing it in the pages folder and renaming it to `auth.vue`. But it is still the same. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a few trials I found the problem was I didn't add a / before `auth/signup`. Changing this to `/auth/signup` fixed the problem.